# Java float is more precise than double?

Tags: java, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, double-precision

Code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print("float: ");
        System.out.println(1.35f-0.00026f);
        System.out.print("double: ");
        System.out.println(1.35-0.00026);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
float: 1.34974
double: 1.3497400000000002
```

??? float got the right answer, but double is adding extra stuff from no where, Why??

Isn't double supposed to be more precise than float?

Comment: try this **System.out.println(String.format("%.20f", 1.35f-0.00026f));**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A float is 4 bytes wide, whereas a double is 8 bytes wide.

Check [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Surely the double has more precision so it has slightly less rounding error.

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. **Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation.** This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

**On a side note:-**

I would suggest if you want the exact decimal values then use `java.math.BigDecimal`

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this is the mechanism of numbers with floating point calculation.
Also when java tries to print a float value, it truncates trailing zeroes.
And, you know, **double** type uses 8 bytes and **float** uses 4. So the **double** precision is bigger.

So, when java calculates your float value, it gets something like 1.3497400 and truncates it before output.
And when java calculates your double value, it gets more digits and so you get such result.

Try to execute this simple example for better understanding:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            sum += 0.1;
        }
        System.out.println( sum );
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            sum += 0.1;
        }
        System.out.println( sum );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you know something about the rules for converting **double** values
>   **to strings**, which are specified by the documentation for **Double.toString** [Java-API], you know that the program prints the shortest decimal fraction sufficient to distinguish the double value
>   from its nearest neighbor, with at least one digit before and after
>   the decimal point.

Check Joshua Bloch's *Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases* - Puzzle 2: Time for a Change. He explains this question in that chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Perversely, you see what you're seeing **because** `double` is more precise than `float`, rather than in spite of it. What you're seeing is a result of how floating point numbers are converted to strings by the default `toString` operation of each class, which depends in part on the precision of the format of the floating point number.

**TL;DR:** The default "to string" operations for `float` and `double` each create strings that only contain as many digits as necessary to uniquely identify the value in the `float` or `double` relative to the adjacent representable values in that same format, rather than outputting **all** digits of the value. Since `double` can represent more values than `float`, its string has to be more precise.

**Details:**

Let's start here: The actual value you get from `1.35f - 0.00026f` isn't `1.34974`, it's `1.34974002838134765625` (since, as you probably know, [not all floating point numbers can be represented in either the `float` or the `double` format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)). The `double` equivalent `1.35 - 0.00026` gives you a more accurate value: `1.349740000000000161861635206150822341442108154296875`. (I used [baseconvert.com](https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point)'s IEEE-754 converter for these, double-checking the 32-bit results against [h-schmidt.net](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and by using the code below.) Let's see that by using `BigDecimal` to format those values to strings rather than `toString` ([live copy](https://ideone.com/V8CBrT)):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Example {
    private static String format(float value) {
        return new BigDecimal(value).toPlainString();
    }
    private static String format(double value) {
        return new BigDecimal(value).toPlainString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        float  f = 1.35f - 0.00026f;
        double d = 1.35  - 0.00026;

        System.out.println("Float:  " + format(f));
        // "Float:  1.34974002838134765625"

        System.out.println("Double: " + format(d));
        // "Double: 1.349740000000000161861635206150822341442108154296875"
    }
}
```

In fact, neither `1.35` nor `0.00026` is precisely held by either `float` or `double` either, so the imprecision kicks in even before the subtraction.

Okay, so why is `float`'s `toString` giving you just `"1.34974"` when `double`'s `toString` gives you `"1.3497400000000002"`? Because the `toString` methods of both classes ([`float`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)), [`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))) produce the shortest (usually) output for a value that differentiates it from the representable values adjacent to it on either side.

With `float`, because `float` is quite imprecise, the short string `"1.34974"` is enough to identify the value the `float` actually contains (and not one of the values next to it). That is, even though the actual value is `1.34974002838134765625`, not all of those digits are needed to differentiate it from other representable `float` values, all you need in the realm of `float` is `"1.34974"`. `Float.parseFloat("1.34974")` gives you the `float` value `1.34974002838134765625` again.

Not so for `double`, though, because `double` has more representable values than `float` does, so the string `"1.34974"` doesn't uniquely identify the `double` value `1.349740000000000161861635206150822341442108154296875`. In fact, if you parse `"1.34974"` as a `double`, you get `1.3497399999999999398170302811195142567157745361328125` instead. So it has to include more digits to differentiate the `double` value you're making into a string from other `double` values — because `double` is more precise than `float`.